# chamar função de dentro da mesma classe

Tags: php

Estou com um problema de **redirecionamento** dentro do **construtor** da `classe`.

Seguinte:

Tenho a `classe`:

```
<?php
 class Constantes {
     
    private $livre = false;
    ...

    public function __construct () {    

       if($this->livre == false) {
           header("Location: ".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/manutencao.php");
           exit;
       }
      
      .....

 }
?>
```

Bom, é necessário que o redirecionamento seja feito ali no `__construct` pois tenho várias chamadas à essa classe e mudar tudo seria um trabalho enorme e uma possível manutenção muito difícil.

O redirecionamento está sendo feito. Mas está duplicando o **$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]**.

O que fazer?

Ao invés de sair para

http://www.gasmuriae.com.br/manutencao.php

Está redirecionando para

http://www.gasmuriae.com.br/www.gasmuriae.com.br/manutencao.php

Comment: Pode sim é só chamar `$this-> minhaFuncao();`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs\gasmuriae.com.br\_controlls\_util\Constantes.php on line 181

Comment: você criou uma função para redirecionar para uma outra página ?

Comment: Mas você chamar a sua função dentro de outra não pode ficar perdida no meio do corpo da classe.

Comment: sim! exataemnte

Comment: `$this->minhaFuncao()` porém vai dar erro, se quiser retornar isso use `__construct()`. [link Veja](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: acho que este tipo de pergunta bastante repetida no grupo

Comment: Exato, foi só fazer a chamada dentro do construtor. Obrigado!

Comment: Mas deu erro no redirecionamento. Duplicou o Location:

Comment: tenta somente `header("Location: manutencao.php");`

Comment: Será que dá? Pois são vários arquivos em diretórios e subdiretórios diferentes que podem chamar a classe. E esse arquivo está na rais do site!

Answer (score 1):

Voçê tem utilizar o `$this->`, mas não como está utilizando. Uma [classe](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php) tem uma estrutura, voçê só pode chamar funções utilizando `$this->` dentro de funções.

```
Class minhaClasse {

      $parametro = true;

      public function minhaFuncao () {
          if ($this->parametro == false) header("Location: pagina.php");
      }
  }

$mc = new minhaClasse();
$mc->minhaFuncao();
```

Comment: Alterei a pergunta. Vê se consegue me ajudar nesse problema! Não posso declarar a classe pois são vários arquivos que a declaram

Answer (score 1):

Achei:

```
 $_SERVER["SERVER_PATH"]
```

e não

```
 $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

Obrigado a todos que se esforçaram e deram suas opiniões!